# Cycle through int values

Tags: c#, javascript

I need some input.

Say you have an int-based Enum with values 1 through 10. If you then have a variable that is, say, value corresponding to 7, how can you easiest set it to next value in the given range without going out of bounds? If the value reaches the limit, it should reset itself to first in the range.

I want a one-liner solution to this. I don't want to do ++ and then check and reset value, plus it has to work in both C# and JavaScript. I suppose something in the Math object might be of help, I don't know...

thanks

Comment: "I need some input" - Great, show us what you have so far. "I want a one-liner solution to this." - What if there isn't one? "I don't want to do ++ and then check and reset value." - Fine, don't do that then. "it has to work in both C# and Javascript" - Given that these are two different programming languages I think you are asking a little too much. So back to the beginning, show us what you have so far and I'm sure someone will be happy to help you toward your solution.

Comment: Wow, I think you need to lighten up a bit man...jeez.

Comment: Don't be so harsh Lazarus. The OP has not shown code, but described his current solution (++, check, reset). And C# and JS both borrow their syntax for this low-level stuff from C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Increment, subtract 1, then modulo, then add 1 (since your Enum is 1-based).

```
((++i - 1) % N + 1
```

(N=10, the maximum value your Enum can take on.)

Comment: Out of interest, is it possible to write this short hand code to go back in cycle . For example for enums 0-4 ,  432104321043210.......

Answer (score 5):

If you know the limits and are sure that all numbers between 0 and that upper limit is occupied by an enum you can use the modulo operator

```
myEnum = (myEnum + 1) % maxValue;
```

You may need to typecast:

```
myEnum = (MyEnumType) (((int) myEnum + 1) % maxValue);
```

*EDIT:* I noticed you have one-based enums. If you really need this, then you would have to do as larsman suggests in his answer:

```
// This statement may look weird, but it works :)
myEnum = (myEnum % maxValue) + 1
// Produces (for myEnum with maxValue set to 4, i.e. allows 1,2,3 & 4 as valid values):
//  1 => 2
//  2 => 3
//  3 => 4
//  4 => 1
```